Not able to filter csv files with the SAF
Using an ActivityResultLauncher to gain access to a csv file with the MIME filter "text/csv" doesn't work. In the file chooser dialog box, the file I want to open is greyed and can't be selected. Launching the file chooser is done this way :

myActivityResultLauncher.launch("text/csv");

Selection is possible if I change my file filter to "*/*", but other files type are selectable as well, which is not desired.
Don't know if it may help but the csv file was generated by Libre Office Calc.

Mime types are not very reliable. Wouldn't a filter of *.csv be simpler?

"/csv" seems simpler but, unfortunately,, not more successful... And ".csv" leads to a android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intentexception!
